# How to view the data based on today Date in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to view the data based on today date only

This is the controller code :

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int programId, int hospitalNo  ,DateTime CountDate )
        {
            var stat = _context.STATISTICS.Where(d => d.program_id == programId && d.hospital_no == hospitalNo && d.DATE == CountDate).ToList();
            return View(stat);
           
        }
```

and this is the button which open the view :

I created session parameter saving login date and tried to call it but its not working :

```
  Session["LoginDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    @Html.ActionLink("Statistics", "Edit","Statistics", new {programId  = item.program_id, hospitalNo = item.hospital_id ,CountDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LoginDate"]) }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

How can I view the data based on the today date or read the data from STATISTICS table there is DATE column but the issue the button in another view and I cannot assign the value

item.DATE

How can I do it and view the data depends on today date ?

Answer (score 2):

the data that you pass in Action Link , will pass on to the controller via query params and the system could read only string and  integers there. What you are trying to attempt is to pass a C# object in query params, which was why it might not be working for you. I would suggest you to change your button code like to below:

```
Session["LoginDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

@Html.ActionLink("Statistics", "Edit","Statistics", new {programId  = item.program_id, hospitalNo = item.hospital_id ,CountDate = Session["LoginDate"]), new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

and your controller code like below:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int programId, int hospitalNo  ,string CountDate )
    {
        var stat = _context.STATISTICS.Where(d => d.program_id == programId && d.hospital_no == hospitalNo && d.DATE == DateTime.Parse(CountDate)).ToList();
        return View(stat);
       
    }
```

Comment: I tried but got error on controller code d.DATE = DateTime.Parse   "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: What is the version of .net you are using?

Comment: Instead of the DateTime.Parse you can use Convert.ToDateTime there